# How to determine if a hard disk is hybrid or not

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hybrid-storage

Is there a quick way (like a built-in tool in Windows, or a small third party tool) that can determine if a hard drive is hybrid or not, and if yes shows the size of the SSD portion?

Currently, the only way I know is find out the drive's model and look it up online, which requires internet access on the machine.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: No... Not in a standard way that's exposed to the OS AFAIK.